# Why can an object be accessed using array notation? Why is array notation needed when property name is in variable?

Tags: javascript

Take the following example:

```
var obj = {};

obj.test1 = 'string'; // string
obj['test2'] = 'string'; // string
obj['test3'] = ['string']; // array

var key = 'test4';
//obj.key = 'string' // not working

var key = 'test5';
obj[key] = 'string'; // working

console.log(obj);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1a45vtc/)

Why is it possible to access an object property using array notation (square brackets): `obj['test2'] = 'string';`?

Why does the example at `test4` using dot notation fails, but works using array notation at `test5`?

Comment: Because *property access* via bracket notation is not called "array notation".

Answer (score 3):

> Why is it possible to access an object property using array notation (square brackets): obj['test2'] = 'string';?

Because that's the way JavaScript is defined to work. This isn't "array notation"; it's "square bracket notation".

> Why does the example at test4 using dot notation fails, but works using array notation at test5?

`obj.key` accesses the property on `obj` that has the name "key". Your object has no property named "key", so this produces `undefined`.

`obj[key]` will access the property whose name is the value stored in the variable `key`. `obj['test4']` will access the property with the name "test4" as will `obj['te' + 'st4']`, and so on.

Square bracket notation allows accessing a property based on a string value. Dot notation allows accessing a property by the name actually written in the code.